# How Do I Remove A Set Of Items Only Once From A List?

Tags: java

I have a list that has the items of 2 HashSet within it. I wanted to find the items that appeared in both sets and I wanted to do it by merging the two sets and then since hash sets don't store the same value more than once, remove the hashSet items from the list once.

For instance if i had a list that was: a b b a

and I had a set that was :a b

And i was trying to remove the set from the list I would want the result to be: a b

How do I go about doing this?

```
Set<String> setItemsA = new HashSet<String>();
setItemsA.add("a");
setItemsA.add("b");
setItemsA.add("c");
setItemsA.add("d");

Set<String> setItemsB = new HashSet<String>();
setItemsB.add("a");
setItemsB.add("b");
setItemsB.add("RR");

Set<String> setItemsC = new HashSet<String>();
List<String> cleanedList = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> mergedList = new HashSet<String>();
cleanedList.addAll(setItemsA);
cleanedList.addAll(setItemsB);
mergedList.addAll(cleanedList);

System.out.println(cleanedList);
cleanedList.removeAll(mergedList);
System.out.println(cleanedList);
```

Currently I am getting an empty list because the Hashset is removing all my items form the list but I only want the items that are in the list that match the hashset to be removed, and if there is a second occurance within the list, for it not to be removed.

Comment: What is a "hash list?"

Comment: Sorry I meant hash set. I guess I missed that when I was writing down the problem

Comment: consider the line     mergedList.addAll(cleanedList);
and  cleanedList.removeAll(mergedList); . mergedList has all items of cleaned list and you are cleaning out the items of merged list from cleaned list, it is bound to be empty.

Comment: Yes. But what I am trying to do is make it so that each item that matches is only removed once. I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: I would have expected this to work also, good question.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that there is also an inbuilt method [`Set.retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) for your original requirement of finding an intersection between two sets. As for where your current approach might be going wrong, I'm sure others will point out.

Comment: whats your expected output, because your question is kind of unclear to me towards the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambdas for this:

```
setItemsA.stream().filter(item -> setItemsB.contains(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above will then only return items in setA that occur in setB - this works for your problem case for all scenarios:

1. If the item exists in A and not B it will not be returned
2. If the item exists in B and not A it will not be returned
3. If the item exists in A and in B it will be returned

Answer (score 2):

The [removeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method will delete all matched object from the provided collection, in your case all String objects in cleanedList are matched to mergedList, if you want subtraction then use [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) to remove first matched object in list

```
cleanedList --> [a, b, c, d, RR, a, b]
mergedList -->   [RR, a, b, c, d]
```

In your case for subtraction

```
for(String s:mergedList) {
            cleanedList.remove(s);
        }
  cleanedList --> [a, b]
```